# Visual Studio hotkey to switch from XAML to code-behind in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have looked for an answer and I found `shift+F7` Or `F7` but none of them works. When I press `F7` I get this error :

> There is no editor available for C:\MySolution\text\Mytest.xaml
>
> Make sure the application for the file type (.xaml) is installed.

*I am running visual studio 2017.*

Answer (score 5):

Install CodeMaid, than `CTRL+M, ,`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried, right clicking a xaml file and "open with..." to ensure there is a xaml editor defined in visual studio?

F7 works for me, though I did right click and "open with..." on xaml files the other week to get visual studio to use the correct xaml editor so I had intellisense in the xaml files.

Comment: What if I actually don't have the "Xaml Editor" in "Open with..." (Although having all Visual Studio default components installed to work with XAML)? (I use it for Xamarin.Forms though).

Comment: looks like "Xaml Designer" is what its called these days.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CTRL + ALT + F7`. Works for me for `Pages`, but not for `Application`. Probably because of Resharper.

Comment: Unfortunately, any of the combinations I tried didn't work. Neither for Pages nor App. Only F7 from XAML editor to code-behind direction.
Possibly because of VS version (15.7), but not 100% sure.